# Validating fields based on old values in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to validate model based on eloquent models old values?

For example I do not want to be able to save field status to PUBLISHED directly from DRAFT status. It has to be APPROVED to go to PUBLISHED status.

For example, I can validate a model with these rules:

```
 private $rules = array(
        'color' => 'required|alpha|min:3',
        'status'  => 'required',
        // .. more rules here ..
    );
```

So whenever I try to fill `status` with `null` value , validation will not pass.

What I need is also to not allow to change status from value 1 to 3, something like

```
 private $rules = array(
        'color' => 'required|alpha|min:3',
        'status'  => 'required|cant_be_changed_from_1_to_3_directly',
        // .. more rules here ..
    );
```

Comment: i think u need to be way more specific and format the question in a better way https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you elaborate it with an example so that I can help you out!

Comment: I tried to add some example